# Codeigniter HMVC обращение к контроллерам Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

У меня есть модуль Админки, находится в modules/admin, и там лежит дефолтный контроллер админки – **modules/admin/controllers/admin**.

Каждый сайт имеет свои уникальные контроллеры, и они должны находиться в папке **application/controllers/admin/controller_name**.

А HMVC показывает 404 ошибку, если не находит modules/admin/controller_name, т.е. если адрес site.ru/admin/controller_name

Как это реализовать и возможно ли вообще?

**Codeigniter 3.0**

Comment: Пожалуйста, воздержитесь от создания такой метки как "3.0" в дальнейшем. Если есть желание добавить в метки именно *"Codeigniter 3.0"* - пишите через дефис: "codeigniter-3.0". А то у вас получились две отдельные метки...

Answer (score 1):

В codeigniter ссылки на функции в контроллере реализуются **site.ru/index.php/controller/func**, если конечно вы не меняли .haccess